# Stepping through regex pattern matches in Python:

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

In python:

1. Assignment is not allowed in conditionals.
2. The state of a regex match is determined based on a returned match object that also contains other match info.

Now say we want to match a particular pattern out of 10 or 15, we end up with something cluttered like this:

```
m = pat1.match(buffer)
if m:    
    tok = tok1
    val = m.group(0)
else:
    m = pat2.match(buffer)
    if m:
        tok = tok2 
        val = m.group(0)
    else:
        m = pat3.match(buffer)
        if m:
            tok = tok3
            val = m.group(0)
            # extra processing here and there - makes looping unsuitable
        else:
            m = pat4.match(buffer)
            if m:
                tok = tok4
                val = m.group(0)
            else:    
                # ... keep indenting
```

We would really like to have something as follows:

```
if match ... pat1:
    tok = 
    val = 
elif match ... pat2:
    tok = 
    val = 
elif match ... pat3:
    tok = 
    val = 
...
```

(like can be done in other languages possibly using features like: assignment in conditionals, side effect to a standard match object, a different form of match function with pass by reference args ...)

We can maybe use a loop to run through the patterns, but that wouldn't be suitable
if there are variations in the processing for each match.

So: is there any nice pythonic way to keep the match conditionals at the same level?!

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the token and patterns in pairs, so you can adjust the following:

```
for pat, token in zip([pat1, pat2, pat3], ['tok1', 'tok2', 'tok3']):
    m = pat.match(buffer)
    if m:
        val = m.group(0)
        tok = token1
        break
```

The idea is you build up a table before hand of pattern -> values:

```
tests = [
    (re.compile('([a-z]{2})'), 'func1'),
    (re.compile('(a{5}'), 'token2')
]

for pattern, token in tests:
    m = pattern.match(buffer)
    if m: 
        # whatever
```

This could further be extended to provide a callable instead which could take the compiled object and buffer as arguments and do whatever it wants from that and returns a value.

eg:

```
def func1(match, buf):
    print 'entered function'
    return int(buf) * 50

tests = [ 
    (re.compile('\d+'), func1)
]

for pattern, func in tests:
    m = pattern.match(buffer)
    if m:
        result = func(m, buffer)
```

Comment: Loop is not desired - there can be variations in the processing for each branch - pls check the question.

Comment: @BaselShishani the closest you can get is to use a dispatch model then... see updated answer - of course, both items in tests could be a callable, and not just compiled re objects

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answers by the way.